# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, minitest

My test fails due to the uniqueness email validation in the user model. I could resolve the issue and make the test green by simply explicitly creating two new users with different email attributes. However the code below also seems to work but it's not quite clear to me.

If someone could help me understand the difference, I'd appreciate it. How is the user ct2 different than user in ct1 created by the factory?

Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :classroom_template do
    association :user, factory: :student
    name "Intro to Github"
    description "Introduction Course to Github"
    ct_type "Self-paced"
  end
end
```

ClassroomTemplateTest.rb

```
it "must be ordered by name" do
  ct1 = FactoryGirl.create(:classroom_template)
  ct2 = FactoryGirl.build(:classroom_template, name: "Intro to Rails", user: ct.user)
  ct1.name.must_equal "Intro to Github"
  ct2.name.must_equal "Intro to Rails"
end
```

Comment: It depends on your user factory. Show that. Also, what is `ct` in `ct.user` in your test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However the code below also seems to work but it's not quite clear to me

It works because the `ct2` below is not persisted yet! Please check by using `ct2.persisted?`, you are building `ct2` in memory, the validations haven't been run!

> ct2 = FactoryGirl.build(:classroom_template, name: "Intro to Rails", user: ct.user)

To avoid duplicating email, I'm using this in my project:

```
factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user_#{n}@factory.com" }
    # Other attributes
end
```

This just makes sure email will be generated differently.